# How to handle array in xml / xsd for generating a POJO class?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

Sample XML response from REST WS -

```
<UserInfoDataContract xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Interzoic.SSO.Shared"  xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<DisplayName>Test User</DisplayName>
<Email>test@test.com</Email>
<FirstName>Test</FirstName>
<IsSuperUser>false</IsSuperUser>
<LastName>User</LastName>
<Password>testuser1</Password>
<PortalID>0</PortalID>
<Roles xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
<a:string>Registered Users</a:string>
</Roles>
<UserID>43</UserID>
<Username>testuser</Username>
</UserInfoDataContract>
```

XSD generated using http://xmlgrid.net/xml2xsd.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
      <!-- XML Schema Generated from XML Document on Thu Apr 09 2015 11:18:33 GMT-0500 (CDT) -->
      <!-- with XmlGrid.net Free Online Service http://xmlgrid.net -->
   <xs:element name="UserInfoDataContract">
          <xs:complexType>
                 <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="DisplayName" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="Email" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="FirstName" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="IsSuperUser" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="LastName" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="Password" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="PortalID" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="Roles">
                               <xs:complexType>
                                      <xs:sequence>
                                             <xs:element name="a:string" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                         </xs:sequence>
                                      <xs:attribute name="xmlns:a" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                  </xs:complexType>
                           </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="UserID" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="Username" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                 <xs:attribute name="xmlns" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                 <xs:attribute name="xmlns:i" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
             </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
```

When i try to create JAXB Classes from the above XSD in eclipse, it gives me errors related to

```
<xs:attribute name="xmlns" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="xmlns:i" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
```

and

```
<xs:attribute name="xmlns:a" in Roles element
```

and

```
<xs:element name="a:string" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
```

So i removed them and added

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Interzoic.SSO.Shared"  xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"  targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
```

on the top.

How will the "Roles" from my XML be referenced in the XSD so that i can create a correct POJO class?

Taking reference from http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#ListDt, lists should be declared this way

```
<xsd:simpleType name="listOfMyIntType">
<xsd:list itemType="myInteger"/>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

I am not able to figure out how i can apply this to my XSD. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think in xml in

`<Roles xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">`

the `xmlns:a` 
is considered as attribute by the ide that generates xsd, that's why in  generated schema you have

```
<xs:attribute name="xmlns" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
```

So I agree with deleting

```
<xs:attribute name="xmlns:a" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="xmlns" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="xmlns:i" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
```

from xsd.

My only guess is try setting

```
targetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Interzoic.SSO.Shared"
```

as it is used explicitly in your xml

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't make any difference. What do you think i should replace `<xs:element name="Roles">                             <xs:complexType><xs:sequence>
                                             <xs:element name="a:string" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                         </xs:sequence>
                                      <xs:attribute name="xmlns:a" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                  </xs:complexType>
                           </xs:element>` with to compensate <a:string> of Roles?

Comment: I think you need to delete attributes with xmlns names as I said. But then your xml probably would not validate against xsd. Do you know why they put xmlns into xml that they are sending you? may be they have their own xsd schema that you need to include?